# Loading test data from MySQL database

Tags: sql, database, ruby

I use Ruby with Selenium to do test automation on a web application that has a MySQL DB behind it.  I need a good way to load data into the DB from a Ruby script.  So far in my research I have found using an export of the DB tables in CSV files and then loading the files back into the DB before running a test that requires the data.  To connect to the DB I have found the gems [mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) and [net/ssh/gateway](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh-gateway).

Does this approach make sense or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds basically right. The only change I might make is instead of loading up to a CSV, you can just take a [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) and load the DB from the dump at the beginning of the script.

Comment: What's the advantage of your approach in comparison to the approach in question?

Comment: As far as the machine is concerned, I don't think much.  That's the reason I used 'might'.  I think this is a good thread to read some opinions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467452/dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line

Comment: Actually just remembered the reason I wrote that - in a case where you want to start with a clean database, you can have a script delete all tables from the DB and then use the mysqldump to create the schema and insert the data.